# Spring-MVC 3.2 to 4.1 Upgrade: @RequestParam Not Binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am upgrading from Spring 3.2 to 4.1 and attempting to update my MVC configuration.

Short version: I can confirm that the request sends the param:

```
userId:USERNAME
password:PASSWORD
termsAccepted:true
```

Content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Spring Security CSRF is disabled:`<security:csrf disabled="true"/>`

Looking at the XSD, it says my custom method argument resolvers do NOT override the default ones:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.jason.web.util.RetainUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"/>
        <bean class="org.jason.web.util.ConversationArgumentResolver"/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Can anyone offer any insight?

Edit: Here's the controller. Nothing special here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login**")
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
                        @RequestParam(value = "submit", required = false) String submit,
                        @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = false) String userId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "password", required = false) String password,
                        @RequestParam(value = "returnView", required = false) String returnView,
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpSession session
    ) {
    // login log. Return a Spring ModelAndView based on success/failure.
}
```

Comment: Do you extend the correct class / implement the correct interface for the custom argument resolvers? As that changed from older versions (although I assume you have used ultimately `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.). Can you post your full configuration and also maybe your controller. Do you also do code upgrades or only a framework upgrade? (It should more or less be a drop in replacement actually).

Comment: Yes, my customer resolvers implement HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. Shouldn't the binding of request parameters to controller method parameters by a built-in converter that I do not have to explicitly define?

I haven't done much in the way of code updates, mostly configuration files.

Comment: Also it is only a warning from your IDE, does your code actually work? The fact that you have a warning in your IDE doesn't mean anything. It indeed doesn't override them it complements them.

Comment: It's not just a warning. The userid passed by the POST request is literally not being bound to the `@RequestParam String userId` in the login method.

Comment: are you posting `userid` or `userId` as those are different keys. Also I would expect the request send to contains `userId=<somevalue>` and not `userId:<somevalue>`.

Comment: I am posting userId. This worked fine for Spring 3.2 and Spring Security 3.2.

Comment: Are you also upgrading Spring Security? And does it even reach your controller?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded Spring Security to 4.1.0.RELEASE, and it gets to the controller method, ultimately throwing an error because of not having the userId value.

Comment: Which is due to Spring Security... The default login url changed from `/j_spring_security_check` to `/login`... Which submit the form to that url instead and you are basically getting the forward/redirect after a login error.

Comment: That did it. If you can post that as a real answer, I'll accept it. If you were anywhere near me, I'd buy you a beer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of your upgrade you also upgraded Spring Security to 4.1. Between 3.2 and 4.x the default login url changed for `/j_spring_security_check` to `/login`. (See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3010).

Now effectively Spring Security handles requests to `/login` and your controller eventually receives the redirect due to an authentication failure (which doesn't contain the original parameters as it is a new empty request).

Comment: That did it, thanks! I changed the mapping of my custom login controller and it worked.